# How to "break" out of a case...while in Ruby

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, control-flow

So, I've tried `break`, `next` and `return`. They all give errors, `exit` of course works, but that *completely* exits. So, how would one end a `case...when` "too soon?"

Example:

```
case x
    when y; begin
        <code here>
        < ** terminate somehow ** > if something
        <more code>
    end
end
```

(The above is some form of pseudo-code just to give the general idea of what I'm asking [begin...end was used with the hope that `break` would work].

And, while I'm at it, is there a more *elegant* way of passing blocks to `case...when`?

Comment: just re-structure your logic - see below

Comment: Just as a quick note, you can't `break` out of a `case` in Ruby. I tried doing that and it generated a syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
case x
when y;
    <code here>
    if !something
        <more code>
    end
end
```

Note that `if !something` is the same as `unless something`

Comment: Absolutely nothing! It did cross my mind, but I was looking for the _right_ way of doing it. I assumed there was a right way, apart from this one. So, if there's no other way of doing it, I guess _this_ is the right way. Thanks! :D

Comment: Wrong is indentation. If it wasn't wrong, then the language won't need at all neither `break` nor `next`.

Answer (score 5):

I see a couple of possible solutions.
At the first hand, you can define your block of instructions inside some method:

```
def test_method
  <code here>
  return if something
  <more code>
end

case x
  when y
    test_method
end
```

At the other hand, you can use `catch-throw`, but I believe it's more uglier and non-ruby way :)

```
catch :exit do
  case x
    when y
      begin
        <code here>
        throw :exit if something
        <more code>
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, if I created a method for every case it would look weird, really weird (and there's a lot of cases) and the second example _does_ look a bit... Eh. +1 for creativity, though.

Comment: but wait, that return only returns from the method and doesn't break the case statement, right?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby has no built-in way to exit the "when" in a "case" statement. You could however get the desired outcome with an answer similar to the technique [WarHog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791619/warhog) gave:

```
case x
when y
    begin
        <code here>
        break if something
        <more code>
    end while false
end
```

or if you prefer:

```
case x
when y
    1.times do
        <code here>
        break if something
        <more code>
    end
end
```

Comment: That would exit the inner loop. Not the case-when. Try adding a `puts "this should not be written"` after the loop and make the break condition true

Comment: user9869932 - good point , you are correct since Ruby has no built-in way to exit the "when" in a "case" statement. this answer is a suggested way to get the desired outcome. guess it assumes that code you want to skip is within the loop.

Comment: looping over something only once?  You've got to be kidding me.