# How to break out of case statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method as follows:

```
def something(param)
  case param
  when 1
    break if <already executed for some similar data>
    #Some code
  when 2
    #Some code
  else
    #Some code
  end
end
```

If `param` is `1`, I will create a record in DB. In such case, I need to check that the same data are not present already, and if so, I need to break out of `when`.

When I try `break if <condition>`, I get this error:

```
Can't escape from eval with break
```

As a solution, I can change `param`'s value before the case statement so that it (`when 1`) never meets the condition:

```
def something(param)
  param = 0 if <condition>
  case param
  when 1
    .
    .
```

but I feel it's ugly.

`break` is used to break out of loops, but I need an equivalent of it here that works like switch statement` break.

```
a = 1
b = 1

case a
when 1
  return if b == 1
  p "Code Executed"
end
```

gives me:

```
LocalJumpError: unexpected return
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022865/how-to-break-out-of-a-case-while-in-ruby

Comment: @LucasNelson Hey, Lucas. Thank you for pointing this post. But can you please see my edit.

Comment: From the comment in the answer, feels like your sorted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is all you have in the method body, then just do `return` instead of `break`.

If you cannot do that, then do:

```
when 1
  unless <already executed for some similar data>
    #Some code
  end
when 2
...
```

Comment: @Abhi To use `return` you'll have to be inside a method body. In your edit, it's not inside a method, that's why it's throwing `LocalJumpError`.